# Mobile _Layout.Mobile.cshtml and iPad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created the layout for mobile devices - _Layout.Mobile.cshtml 
there own scripts, their styles, all okay, on tablets computers loaded full version of the website (_Layout.cshtml).

On mobile phones loaded mobile version (_Layout.Mobile.cshtml)

BUT iPads (though he refers to the tablet PC) is loaded mobile version

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my knowledge, you need to tell the DisplayModeProvider that iPads should get the default display mode (the desktop view).

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode()
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });
```

The code is fairly explanatory, you insert a mode that is the default with the context of iPad being in the user agent.

See more here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features under "Browser-Specific Views"

This should go in the Application_Start() method of your Global.asax.cs